# What is the right way to get number of items from a field?

Tags: 8, entities

In code review I saw a developer using count($paragraph->field_events) to get the number of referenced entities.

I thought, surely that can't work, that can't be right.  So the question is, what is the correct way to get the number of items from a field on an entity?

Answer (score 10):

Using count() on a field is acceptable because there is an implementation of [Countable::count](http://php.net/manual/fr/countable.count.php) in the ListInterface implemented by ItemList class where it overloads the count method to count the items, from which FieldItemList and EntityReferenceFieldItemList inherit.

So you can use:

```
$paragraph->field_events->count()
```

or

```
count($paragraph->field_events)
```

synonymously.  They do the same thing.

From ItemList.php:

```
public function count() {
  return count($this->list);
}
```

If you'd like test this, you can play with this [simple class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8510094/1214689).  If you remove the "Implements Countable" calling count(a) on object a doesn't return the count() method, but if you add it back, it does.  So on a low level, Drupal is using this so you can call count() on fields.